# ¿Como puedo hacer que python muestres varias gráficas con este código?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def traza_curvas(series, colores, nombres):
    ''' Traza varias curvas a partir de varias series de puntos

    Además de la serie de puntos, se toma como entrada una serie de
    etiquetas y una serie de colores. Se debe comprobar que las tres
    series tienen el mismo número de elementos.
    Puede ser de utilidad la función 'built-in' zip
    '''
    for serie, color, nombre in zip(series, colores, nombres):
        print("Entra en el for:")
        print("serie:",serie[:5])
        print("color",color)
        print("nombre:",nombre)
    plt.plot(serie, label=label, color=color)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


# Test de la función traza_curvas
colores = ['blue', 'red', 'orange', 'grey']
```

Comment: Hola Tony. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Puedes explicar mejor lo que necesitas?
 Tu codigo actual tiene errores? Mejora la explicacion siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

La llamada a `plt.plot` debe hacerse dentro del for, de forma que se cree una nueva curva por cada serie de puntos. Tal y como lo tienes ahora solo te va a mostrar la última curva.

Para validar basta con que uses un condicional con `len` y lances una excepción si los tres argumentos tiene distinta longitud.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def traza_curvas(series, colores, nombres):
    ''' Traza varias curvas a partir de varias series de puntos

    Además de la serie de puntos, se toma como entrada una serie de
    etiquetas y una serie de colores. Se debe comprobar que las tres
    series tienen el mismo número de elementos.
    Puede ser de utilidad la función 'built-in' zip
    '''
    if len(series) != len(colores) or len(series) != len(nombres):
        raise ValueError("Las tres series deben tener el mismo tamaño")
    for serie, color, nombre in zip(series, colores, nombres):
        plt.plot(serie, label=nombre, color=color)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


# Test de la función traza_curvas
series = [[0, 4,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10],
          [0, 1,  1.5,  2,  3,  7,  7.5], 
          [0,  5,  7,  8,  14,  14.5,  16], 
          [0,  0.5,  1,  1.5,  2,  2.5,  3]]
colores = ['blue', 'red', 'orange', 'grey']
nombres = [ "Serie 1", "Serie 2", "Serie 3", "Serie 4"]
traza_curvas(series, colores, nombres)
```

**Salida:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]